# Firebase Notification Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to send a notification with Firebase. However, in some cases, the notification does not called the onReceive method.
Foregound = Call and navigate. 
Background and Kill App = onReceive not called. I can not get the data and not redirect.

https://gist.github.com/Omurtekinn/fcbd3ba2e83925c459b22d5614c3ea00
MyFirebaseMessaging class.

[baslik=title / özel veriler= data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smXye.png)

Comment: is your manifest file with the things needed by firebase messaging ?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml
https://gist.github.com/Omurtekinn/5c2650af61e9819b283635c84ee0daa4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) you'll see that Android handle notification messages differently depending on the payload and if your app is on the foreground or background:

If your app is in the **foreground** you'll always receive the notification in the `onMessageReceived` method. Not matter the payload of the notification.

If it is on the **background** you have two scenarios:

*Notification payload:*
Message is delivered to system tray and when you click it it'll be delivered to the Launch Activity through intent extras.

*Data payload:*
Message will be delivered to `onMessageReceived`.

Looking into your scenario it seems you have a notification payload. You have two options:

1) Change the payload type to data. If you're using the FCM console you can only do option 2 because it will only send Notification messages.

2) Implement the receiving of the message in the launcher activity onCreate method.

The notification basically looks like this:

```
 {
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
  }
```

If you're adding key/value pairs it will look like this:

```
 {
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

In your launcher activity you get the notification in the intent extras like any other activity, in onCreate():

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras!=null){
    String notification = extras.getString("notification");
    String dats = extras.getString("data");
  }
```

Note that if you're using android O you need to configure the [channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl#ManageChannels) as well.

Comment: Hi , 
I inserted the question that I sent the data in the FCM console.
How can Implement the receiving  I run in the onCreate method

Comment: It did not work.Not called onReceived when the application works in the background.

Comment: Your app won't call onReceived when it is in the background, not even if you implement my solution. As I said before , due to the payload type of your notification it will **always** go to the onCreate() of your launcher activity when your app is in the background. The code I provided is to retrieve the notification data when the user taps the notification in the tray.

Comment: I understand now. Do I need to send the data as intent to extras in my class? Because the extras in your code are return null.

Comment: what's the api level your app is running on?

Comment: api level 26. Android 8.0.0

Comment: You need to configure notification channels as well, have you done that?https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl#ManageChannels

Comment: so let me understand, you still don't receive a notification in you system tray when your app is in the background?

Comment: No no. I get a notification, but I can not pull in the data. Bundle  When I click  Notification null will return. (I'm sory,My English is very bad)

Comment: your eglish is great, don't worry :) what about this?  String dats = extras.getString("data"); is this null?

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
extras is null.

Comment: you added the code to the launcher activity? In your case LoginActivity?